# AlamofireImage addAuthentication not adding Authorization header

Tags: authentication, alamofireimage

I'm using the UIImageView.af_setImage extension to download images from a webdav server which requires authentication.

Based on the docs which say...

> If an image requires and authentication credential from the UIImageView extension, it can be provided as follows:
>
> ```
> ImageDownloader.default.addAuthentication(user: "user", password: "password")
> ```

...I have tried adding authentication 2 different ways:

```
ImageDownloader.default.addAuthentication(user: "user", password: "password")
```

and when that didn't work

```
UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.addAuthentication(user: "user", password: "password")
```

However, neither appear to be sending the Authorisation header to the HTTP request.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `addAuthentication()`, I solved it by installing my own `UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader` that adds the `Authorization: Bearer yZyq6jYn78Ia9EOysUV8kQ` header.

## Swift

```
import Alamofire
import OAuthSwiftAlamofire
import OAuthSwift
import AlamofireImage

class MyNetwork {
    lazy var sessionManagerForImageDownloader: SessionManager = {
        let configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = ImageDownloader.defaultURLSessionConfiguration()
        let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        sessionManager.adapter = self.oauth2Swift.requestAdapter
        sessionManager.retrier = self.oauth2Swift.requestAdapter
        sessionManager.startRequestsImmediately = false
        return sessionManager
    }()

    func setup() {
        // Glue AlamofireImage with OAuthSwift
        // When `af_setImage()` is invoked, then the it will inserts
        // the header field "Authorization: Bearer yZyq6jYn78Ia9EOysUV8kQ"
        UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader = ImageDownloader(sessionManager: sessionManagerForImageDownloader)
    }

    lazy var oauth2Swift: OAuth2Swift = {
        return OAuth2Swift(
            consumerKey:    "clientID",
            consumerSecret: "clientSecret",
            authorizeUrl:   "https://example.com/login",
            accessTokenUrl: "https://example.com/login",
            responseType:   "code"
        )
    }()
}
```